# Пунктуация в предложении со словом "понятно"

Tags: пунктуация

Это слишком сложное для меня предложение. [Справочник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_574) по пунктуации не сильно помог. Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

> Как просто указать стрелку понятно с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип понятно `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`

Нашёл в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/293186/17429) и засомневался в том, что надо использовать тире.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как просто указать стрелку, понятно: с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип, понятно: `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.

Тут главное вот что:

1. До «понятно» ***обязательно*** должен быть какой-то знак препинания. Иначе «понятно» влипает в предыдущее предложение — и смысл его искажается: становится что-то вроде «как понятно указать стрелку», то есть теперь `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` у нас не просто *указывает стрелку*, а *указывает стрелку понятно*.
2. После «понятно» тоже ***обязательно*** должен быть какой-то знак препинания. Иначе «понятно» влипает в последующее предложение — и смысл его искажается: теперь с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` мы *понимаем, как указать стрелку*, вместо того, чтобы *указывать её*.

То есть «понятно» нужно с двух сторон отделить какими-то знаками, иначе смысл кардинально исказится. Какими знаками — это во многом на Ваше усмотрение.

До «понятно» можно поставить:

- запятую (если мы воспринимаем это в стиле «понятно, как просто [...]»);
- тире ([§ 138.1.1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#ppp_1); параллелизм структуры усиливает желание поставить тире);
- вопросительный знак.

После «понятно» можно поставить:

- если мы воспринимаем «понятно» не как вводное, а как сказуемое:

  - тире ([§ 45.7](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#ppp_7));
  - двоеточие ([§ 44.1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#ppp_1) или [§ 44.3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#ppp_3));
  - открывающаяся скобка;
- запятую, если мы считаем «понятно» просто вводным словом.

> Как просто указать стрелку — понятно (с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`). Как убрать логотип — понятно (`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`). Но как и убрать логотип приложения, и отобразить стрелку — непонятно.

---

<sub>Ниже идёт старый вариант ответа:</sub>

> > <sub><s>Как просто указать стрелку, понятно с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип, понятно `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.</s></sub>
>
> <sub>-- такая пунктуация означала бы, что мы "*понимаем с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`*". Теоретически такое возможно, т.к. многое может быть понятно благодаря одному только наличию этого метода в списке методов. Но на самом деле это немного бред, т.к. обычно люди понимают с помощью документации/мозгов, а метод `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` -- это уже то, с помощью чего люди это делают (указывают стрелку), а не то, с помощью чего люди понимают, как это сделать.</sub>
>
> > <sub>Как просто указать стрелку? Понятно, с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип? Понятно, `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.</sub>
>
> <sub>Или авторские варианты:</sub>
>
> > <sub>Как просто указать стрелку? Понятно! С помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип? Понятно: `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.</sub>

Comment: По-моему хороший ответ. Единственное, я бы после _понятно_ ставил тире.

Comment: Пунктуацией здесь можно организовать практически любой смысл. Как просто указать стрелку "понятно"? С помощью метода BlaBlaEnabled. Как убрать логотип - понятно: AblAblAbled(false).

Answer (score 2):

Возможно несколько вариантов.  Если нужно оставить это одним предложением, то вот так:

> Как просто указать стрелку - понятно: с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип - понятно: `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть тут:
Как просто указать стрелку, понятно с помощью метода setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled. Как убрать логотип, понятно setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
Мне кажется, тут скорее ЭТО ПОНЯТНО С ПОМОЩЬЮ. Само предложение построено немного неверно. Тут скорее подошло бы : " То, как быстро указать стрелку, вам будет понятно с помощью метода ..." и " То, как убрать логотип, вам будет понятно"

Comment: Нет, точно нет. Человек имеет в виду, что ему понятно, как указать стрелку, и дальше поясняет (это делается с помощью метода...)

Answer (score 0):

Из-за нескольких значений слова "понятно", по-русски фразы звучат довольно коряво. Лучше заменить синонимами, а какими зависит от вкладываемого вами смысла:

> Как просто указать стрелку? Конечно же с помощью метода...
>   Как убрать стрелку? Конечно же - ...
>   Как просто указать стрелку можно понять с помощью метода...
>   Как убрать стрелку видно из...

Comment: Нет, посмотрите контекст, там идёт именно: `Как сделать это, мне понятно (так-то). Как сделать то, мне тоже понятно (так-то). Как сделать и это, и то -- непонятно.`

Answer (score -1):

Эти предложения сложны и для меня, русского.

По http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire

**Первое предложение**

Правило 168:

Как просто указать стрелку понятно - с помощью метода setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled.

**Второе предложение**

Правило 164:

Как убрать логотип понятно - setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false).

Comment: Насчёт применимости 168 сомневаюсь, а вот со 164 точно не согласен... Подлежащее `логотип`, а сказуемое — имя метода? Так чтоли? Я что-то никак не могу понять, как здесь применить это правило.

Comment: я, кстати, русский. Просто не очень грамотный :)

Comment: Применимость 168 - я сам бы обычно написал двоеточие. Но сейчас вижу что это неправильно. По поводу 164 у меня сомнений нет: это очевидно категория "Дуб - дерево". Я тоже в пунктуации постоянно путаю двоеточие и тире.

Comment: Выделите, пожалуйста, подлежащее и сказуемое. Так нагляднее.